# Embedding text file into RTF file with python or .net core

Tags: c#, python, .net-core, rtf, ole

I have a requirement which includes file embedding (text files) into a dynamically generated RTF file.

I’m currently able to generate the RTF without problems but I also need to embed one or multiple txt files into it as well.

I’ve done some research and also looked into rtf spec. Looks like there might be a way to do that with \object tag but as far as I understand \objdata content should be in OLE format. Is this the only way? (I was hoping I could include in byte array format) Or is there any way to convert txt file content into this format so that I can include?

I currently have several microservices written in python and c# (dotnet core) and they are all running on docker containers on linux env. So preferably I need a way that’s suitable with these.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aspose.Words allows inserting embedded OLE objects into Word documents and it has .NET Standard 2.0 version. 
https://apireference.aspose.com/net/words/aspose.words.documentbuilder/insertoleobject/methods/2

Comment: Thanks, I think there is not much choice other than these paid options.

Answer (score 0):

I use a pragmatic solution here, which works when text files should be embedded in an RTF document.

1. Save the desired Document as RTF with dummy text at the position of the text to be replaced.
2. Open this RTF with a text editor and replace the `\par` lines with a replacement marker `[!!! replace me !!!]`.

From:

```
    ... prefix rtf stuff ...
    \par text foo
    \par bar text
    \par text baz
    ... suffix rtf stuff ...
```

To:

```
    ... prefix rtf stuff ...
    [!!! replace me !!!]
    ... suffix rtf stuff ...
```

3. Save this as template.rtf
4. In C# read your text file to be embedded into a string prepending each line with `\par<space>`. Read the template into a second string an replace there the marker with the first string.
5. Save this as new.rtf.

Here is an example (sorry Perl only, C# should be a 10 liner, too):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $contents = "";
my $first = 1;
while(<>) {
    if (!$first) {
        $contents .= "\\par ".$_;
    } else {
        $contents .= $_;
        $first = 0;
    }
}

my $file = 'template.rtf';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die;
$/ = undef;
my $data = <$fh>;
close $fh;

$data =~ s/\[!!! replace me !!!\]/$contents/g;

print $data;
```

Call it so:

```
perl mkrtf.pl <test.lst >test.rtf
```